# Как убрать функцию при нажатии на body

Tags: javascript

Есть такой скрипт:

```
function toggle(el) {
el.style.display = (el.style.display == 'none') ? '' : 'none'
}
```

Вызов скрипта:

```
onclick="toggle(tr)"
```

Если нажать в div с onclick toggle(tr) то появляется блок с id = "tr"
и чтобы этот появившийся блок исчез нужно нажать еще один раз в div  с id "tr , так вот, нужно сделать так, чтобы если нажать на любой часть страницы то блок проподает, как это сделать ?

Answer (score 3):

Любая часть страницы - это объект Document. Реализуйте событие "один клик" в Document и "скрывайте" свой div. Доступ к элементу Document (вашему div) осуществляется в порядке доступа к массивам.

Comment: Я не знаю js, дайте пример пожалуйста

Comment: Открывайте поисковик Google или идите в ближайшей книжный магазин. Удачи!

Answer (score 2):

**HTML:**

```
<a href="javascript://" id="click-block">Click</a>
<div class="block"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
a {
   color: #000;
   font: 14px "Trebuchet MS";
}

div.block {
    display: none;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#click-block').live('click', function () {
    var elem = $('div.block');
    elem.show();
});
var check = false;
$('div.block').hover(function () {
    check = true;
}, function () {
    check = false;
});

$(document.body).live('click', function () {
    if ( !check ) $('div.block').hide();
});
```

[**Результат выполнения.**](http://jsfiddle.net/8yt6R/)

Comment: Уважаемый exec, я за Вас объясню Максуду (или сделайте ему коменты в коде) где скрывается его div:
$(document.body).live('click', function () {
    if ( !check ) $('div.block').hide();
});

Comment: @Вячеслав Кириченко, я мало сделал? Пусть сам ищет.

Comment: Вам Респект. Удачи.